# Ender 3 Nozzle does not clear bed

Tags: z-axis, creality-ender-3

I have a thicker glass plate on the bed. Also, I have a z-axis offset at the maximum value 50 yet the nozzle does not clear the plate.

Why can't I adjust the axis beyond 50?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: mind to show a photo? how thick is your glass sheet?

Comment: Please explain with a figure what your problem is. The problem is not very "clear".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to get the Z0 into a position the sotware can account for it without needing to write your own firmware if needed:

- Remove the build-tak-clone under your glass sheet to get the better heat transfer and remove a couple millimeters.
- Tighten the bed leveling to account for some millimeters.
- Move the physical endstop to account for the thicker build platform.

Comment: Moving the endstop switch is what I had to do when I moved to using a glass plate